# How can I model in AnyLogic from code level?

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to create AnyLogic Agent as Java class and then run it in AnyLogic?

I imagined situation like this: I create a Java class which extends Agent and then pass it to Simulation Experiment as "Top-level agent". I tried doing it, but it's not possible to select my class from "Top-level agent" dropdown menu.

I would appreciate every hint on how to model in AnyLogic without using drag&drop mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. There is a (behind-the-scenes) difference between creating a proper agent (drag in agent type onto a canvas) and creating a Java class that `extends Agent` .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically I have to use GUI to build a simulation? I would like to have a database with defined properties for objects (e.g. pallet racks with their location coordinates etc.) and I'd like these objects to be added to the model at the simulation beginning (build or start). I thought that I can write it in Java with use of AnyLogic objects. Do you think it's possible to do it some other way that doesn't require dragging so many elements into canvas?

Comment: well, many objects can be created programmatically at the model start, including pallet racks. Search the Help for "PalletRack API" to see the constructors and methods available. Most (but not all) objects can be created like that

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you recall which kind of objects can't be created like that or how can I get to know that? What about objects from Process Modeling Library?

Comment: Short answer: if their API has a constructor, you are safe. If not, it is a gamble that only AnyLogic support can help with directly